# iOS:How to change notification titles to the same?

Tags: ios, iphone

[image]

Here is my notification, **zhinanmao** is my project name and **Hello** is my Bundle display name, I don't know how to change **zhinanmao** to **Hello** and let them display the same thing.

Comment: You want `Hello` for both the titles?

Comment: yea,both show my Bundle display name.

Answer (score 1):

Follow the image below. Before doing this, please take a **backup** of your project, for just to be safe.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

**It seems iOS Notification System doesn't update notification title immediately.**

I localize my app name in `InfoPlist.strings(Chinese (Simplified))`

```
"CFBundleDisplayName" = "我的应用";
"CFBundleName" = "我的应用";
```

and in `InfoPlist.strings(English)`

```
"CFBundleDisplayName" = "MyApp";
"CFBundleName" = "MyApp";
```

I clean my project, delete and reinstall my app on the device.
But the notification title is still the old one.

After switching to another system language and switching back I get what I want.